# regular expressions solution, Trouble accessing a previously easy to access nba STATS url

Tags: html, url

This might be slightly off topic, but since the solution is a general expressions problem I thought it could be interesting to solve it here.

I am trying to access a URL that has data that I usually scrape for Analysis:

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2011-12&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=0&PlusMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2011-12&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0
```

As you can see in the url it has many fields to be filled, and this url that previously worked now it gives me the following error:

```
The PlayerPosition property is required.
```

So I thought that as in many other fields in the URL if I added

```
&PlayerPosition=0
```

It would use every position, so I used this url:

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2011-12&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=0&PlusMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2011-12&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0&PlayerPosition=0
```

But it gave me the following error:

```
The field PlayerPosition must match the regular expression '^((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))?$'.
```

So I tried replacing &PlayerPosition=0 to:

```
&PlayerPosition=&PlayerPosition='^((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))?$'

&PlayerPosition=&PlayerPosition= ^((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))?$

&PlayerPosition=&PlayerPosition=((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))?

&PlayerPosition=&PlayerPosition=((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))
```

But nothing worked, and it gives me back the same error, any suggestions?

Comment: It means you should set `PlayerPosition=Guard` or `PlayerPosition=Center` or `PlayerPosition=Forward`.

Comment: tried this: `http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2011-12&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=0&PlusMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2011-12&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0&PlayerPosition=Guard`, did not work @Ryan

Comment: It has a list of errors telling you exactly what format it expects… set `SeasonType=Regular Season` (or `Pre Season`, `Playoffs`, etc.), provide a valid `TeamId` and `Month`, and so on...

Comment: I get that, but lets say I want to add the seasonType, and I want multiple options, which is what I was showing up in the question do I do this: `(Regular Season)|(Pre Season)|(Playoffs)|(All Star)$`, include the $, take out the $, how can I add the multiple options

Comment: You ... don't.  Their web service isn't going to give you _all_ the information in one request.  That's why it's giving you choices for fields.  You can either get Regular Season, Pre Season, or Playoffs, but not all three.  If you _need_ all three, you _need_ three requests.

Comment: thanks @g.d.d.c, thats a shame, specially for team info, I use to be able in the prior structure to get all values at the same time, I have a model that I did with five previous seasons, but I need every shot from every player for this year, and making a querry for each team, and then for each position, and again for playoffs and regular season is gonna take a while

Comment: @DerekCorcoran It seems as if `g.d.d.c` has satisfied your question. If you expect no further answers, please self-answer to your question, and accept that answer, so that the question will not anymore be considered unanswered.

Comment: @remdevtec I don't think the problem has been solved, I was wondering that to do about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player position should match against this regex:

```
'^((Guard)|(Center)|(Forward))?$'
```

the `()?` states that everything between the parentheses is optional. So, `(Guard)|(Center)|(Forward)` is optional. **It can be blank**.

Meaning that the following values are all valid:

- PlayerPosition=Guard
- PlayerPosition=Center
- PlayerPosition=Forward
- PlayerPosition=

I've tried in the browser using it without anything after it and it worked:

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2011-12&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=0&PlusMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=2011-12&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0&PlayerPosition=
```

Comment: Thank you Ruby, it worked. Could you add the full URL just for reference for other people?

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter PlayerPosition your url string, where ever you want. But value can be "Guard" or "Center" or "Forward" only.

for example

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=2011-12
  &ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=
  &LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0
  &OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame
  &Period=0&PlayerID=0&PlusMinus=N&Position=&Rank=N&RookieYear=
  &Season=2011-12&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0
  &VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1
  &showZones=0
  &PlayerPosition=Guard
```

Comment: that shows an error `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`

Comment: The first error was about your question. Second error is XML file. Thats mean the url is working but parameters have errors (may be one or more). What are the parameters and how must they to be you know!